# Discord.js args TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a code which converts words like "eu" to "europe" but i keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined if the usage was correct

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const db = require('quick.db')
module.exports = {
    name: 'code',
    description: 'sends your among us code to the codes channel',
    example: 'code AAAAAA eu',
    async execute(message, args, client, prefix) {
        let ch = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}_codechannel`)
        if(ch === null) ch = 'not set'
        if(ch === 'not set') return message.channel.send(`A codes channel has not been set here tell an admin to set it using the config command`)

        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You must join a voice channel')

        const inv = await voiceChannel.createInvite({
            maxAge: 0,
            unique: false,
            maxUses: 100,
        });

        const thecode = args[0];
        if (thecode.length !== 6) return message.reply('The code can only be 6 characters long');
        const thecodeUC = thecode.toUpperCase();
        const region = args[1];
        let r = '';
        if(region.toLowerCase() === 'eu' || region.toLowerCase() === 'europe') r = 'Europe';
        if(region.toLowerCase() === 'na' || region.toLowerCase() === 'northamerica') r = 'North America';
        if(region.toLowerCase() === 'as' || region.toLowerCase() === 'asia') r = 'Asia';
        if(region === 'undefined' || region === '') return message.channel.send('the only regions available are: Europe(eu), Northamerica(na) and Asia(as)');
        
        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(ch)
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00ffff')
        .setAuthor(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
        .setTitle('New Among Us Code')
        .addField('Code', `${thecodeUC}`, true)
        .addField('Region', `${r}`, true)
        .addField('Voice Channel', `[Click Here](${inv})`, true)
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));
        channel.send(embed);
        message.reply(`Sent your code in the codes channel`);

    }
}
```

I'm really confused what's the issue since i have

```
if(region === 'undefined' || region === '') return message.channel.send('the only regions available are: Europe(eu), Northamerica(na) and Asia(as)');
```

to return a message when "region" is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand what it says:
**"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"**

In here you are trying to read and call a function called **toLowerCase**.

```
if(region.toLowerCase() === 'eu'
```

From documentation you can find that this function is a part of String data type:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

This means, that other things, for example **undefined** do not have this function

You might be also confused by the word **property** in "Cannot read **property** 'toLowerCase'. Well, this is because String is a object, and it defines properties. Function **toLowerCase** is a property defined on object String.

String is also what you would call a data type. Hence the **TypeError**.

This means that when JavaScript interpreter reads the line:

```
if(region.toLowerCase() === 'eu' || region.toLowerCase() === 'europe') r = 'Europe';
```

The variable region has a value **undefined**

And the check:

```
if(region === 'undefined' || region === '') return message.channel.send('the only regions available are: Europe(eu), Northamerica(na) and Asia(as)');
```

is performed only after JS trying to read that property.